# An "EQ" for RPi SE

Tags: discussion

I've just looked at the most recent 50 posts on [RPi's Questions page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions). 33 of 50 were from contributors with a single point of "rep". 6 more Q's sourced from reps of 20 or less. If you include the "101`s" (101 rep from another SE site), it seems virtually everyone asking questions here is "new" - under some definition of that word.

OTOH, here are a few other SE sites I use from time to time & the # of questions asked by "1-pointers". Are there any "official" stats on this?

[RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions) has 33 of 50
[Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions) has 27 of 50
[Apple SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions) has 16 of 50
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) has 13 of 50
[U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions) has 12 of 50
[Arduino SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions) has 4 of 50

Comment: This is because of the low entry bar for Pi ownership. The situation gets worse at this time each year as kids unwrap their presents. In fact a number of low rep questions (with  11 rep) are due to the "serial upvoter" who seems to upvote anything, even those poor questions the more experienced users flag for closure.

Comment: @Milliways: I think you may be onto something! Maybe it's just my imagination, but it does seem the question quality has taken a nose dive.

Comment: I think you'll probably find (glorfindel's insightful answer bares this out) that the larger and more active the exchange, the more mature the community and the lower this stat will be.  Part of that is the nature of the beast, but it is compounded by the fact that in order to produce users with higher reps we need more users with reps high enough to vote up -- which 15 seems like a low enough bar, but it is more than 11.  Most users only ask one question (haven't confirmed this but pretty sure it is so); the pi may have a low bar of entry but I suspect a high rate of user attenuation.

Comment: ...In other words, what you see here may reflect the conjecture that a high percentage of the Pis ever made are probably in landfill or gathering dust.

Comment: @goldilocks: I agree w/ all you've said - a possible exception is the *Arduino* case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this SEDE query I just created](https://data.stackexchange.com/raspberrypi/query/1356017/of-last-100-questions-by-new-users), which checks the last 100 questions because the math is easier, Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange sees a lot of questions by new users (about two-thirds), but it's only 21st network-wide. There are sites with three quarters of the questions by new users:

[image]

Most of the top sites are small beta sites, but some sites comparable in size to Raspberry Pi (e.g. Photography and Graphic Design) are also there.

Comment: Oh - that's depressing... 33 of 50 today means that were doing "better than average" today :)  Lots of opportunities here for trend analysis, etc. And thank you for an impressive display of SQL skills!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a "newbie" on several StackExchange forums myself, I would like to contribute a little bit here.

The first time I got a Raspberry (indeed, Christmas, a gift from my son) I had no experience whatsoever with Linux. I think that's the case for most first-time Raspberry owners. Most will know Windows and/or Mac, not Linux.

Linux is overwhelming for new users. Even now, if I want to do something new, it can take many hours or even days to just find out how. I spend a lot of time searching and often something you find refers to a StackExchange board. So no wonder a lot of newbies end up here.

But then, if you appreciate this board, want to contribute something and provide answers yourself, you find that you have no idea how to answer most questions. Because you're a newbie! And compared to the experts, you are busy for many hours to accomplish something that they can do in minutes.

I've just started to answer a few questions myself these last days. But in a list of 100 questions I found only 2 that I could answer. Not all of us are experts.

My point being: everybody starts as a newbie. Try to stimulate them by educating them and don't be condescending. Then maybe a more substantial number of users will start answering questions too. Don't add comments like Milliways in [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120197/rpi3-as-an-access-point-issues). You're scaring users away with that. Help the guy and give him a better link to search. Hashtag letmeduckduckgothatforyou. I'm taking this just as an example I encountered today, but there are many more comments like that to be found.

There are no stupid questions, only stupid answers.

Comment: You've made a good point, but of course we're all biased. Let's be honest & admit two points of view in this Newbie vs. Knowledge discussion. You've now exercised your right to opine on someone's input (the comment you ref'd), just as he exercised his. Isn't that the same thing? RE your summation, my opinion is that stupid answers and stupid questions are both in good supply. Personally, I'm OK with stupid - to a point, but I find "lazy" a little harder to choke down. You might re-cast your view on all of this as a "resource allocation" problem: how should the "resources" be allocated?

Comment: Well, let's take the [other example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120205/shutdown-from-c-program/120206) I answered. Is that a stupid question? Nah. Lazy? Probably. Now look at the comment of the far more experienced joan. Shouldn't I have answered the question? Is joan now disappointed about me because I made it to easy for the question asker? Perhaps I don't understand the vibes here just yet.
But I don't understand your last question, perhaps because English is not my native language. What resources do you mean and why is allocation important?

Comment: @Joep I agree with your answer. For reference though, may I link you to [this page about asking good questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That might explain the comments you're seeing. I think everyone will appreciate it if the asker _demonstrates_ that effort has been made, or make it clear that they don't know where to start (we all need to start somewhere). We don't know how much work the asker did unless they show it, and I understand where the comments you linked came from, given how the questions were asked.